# Stop a certain Windows Store app from updating

Tags: windows-store-app, automatic-update

Is there a way to keep a certain Windows Store app from being updated while all others are kept up to date?

Or is there a way to save a backup of the current version and launch it somehow, even after the updated version was installed?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing that, assuming it's possible?

Comment: @MichaelBay The [Twitter app is going to update](https://www.windowscentral.com/twitter-updates-its-windows-10-uwp-app-pwa-support-push-notifications) from an UWP app to a PWA. The latter has advertisements while the former doesn't. I want to keep using the old version that has no ads.